# <element>.KeyCode is not working in some keyboards?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, keypress, keycode

I am detecting the a pressed key (`<tab>` in this case) inside a text input box. Its ok while i'm coding. But when i test on different computer (a laptop, with same Firefox Version), it returning "Undefined". Why?

For example: When i pressed `<tab>` key, it should return `9`. Instead, it is returning `Undefined` or `0` on some other machines. Why?

Using following JS code:

```
function keyHandler(e) {
  var charCode;
  if (e && e.which) {
      charCode = e.which;
  } else if (window.event) {
      e = window.event;
      charCode = e.keyCode;
  }

  if (charCode == 9) {
    bla.. bla.. bla.. bla.. 
  }
}
```

What i'm amazing is that it works on my `pc` but not on an other `laptop`. Does laptop keyboards have different keycodes?

or why?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
function keyHandler() {
var e = arguments[0] || window.event,
    charCode = e.which || e.keyCode || e.charCode;

  if (charCode == 9) {
    bla.. bla.. bla.. bla.. 
  }
  else {
  console.log( charCode );
  }
}
```

or just use jQuery

Comment: Should be `function keyHandler(e)` .. right? Also it doesn't work on IE :(

Comment: Nope, the `e` variable is defined inside the function and assigned to **first argument** (`arguments[0]`) (or in IE's case, `window.event`, because `arguments[0]` will be `undefined`)

Which IE version are you referring to?

Comment: assigned to first argument (arguments[0]) ?? So pls how the function call from element side will be? I mean will it not be `onkeypress="keyHandler(event);"` ???

Comment: `document.onkeyup = keyHandler;` or if you want it to work only when an element is focused, give the element an ID and do `document.getElementById("elementid").onkeyup = keyHandler` Note: keyup, not keypress. Note that this would be a lot easier with jQuery as you don't have to think about the browser differences in simple tasks.

Comment: `document.getElementById("elementid").onkeyup = keyHandler;` and text input with `<input id="elementid" type="text" />` doesn't work even in Firefox :(

Comment: the input element needs to be rendered before you can call document.getElementById. put a `<script>` tag just before closing `</body>` tag and put the code in there